# Working with node js and angular js and mysql database

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have a `nodejs` file in the local host which connects to `mysql database`. My SQL database has cake table which contains name and price. I want to connect `angular js` to `node js` so that I can retrieve the name and price from the cake table.

Comment: What have you done ? If you haven't do anything, explore express. Try search express + angular.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is normally referred to as a client-side framework, which can be run from a web browser or a native mobile app while your MySQL and NodeJS app are usually referred to as server-side application.

While both of them can be hosted in your localhost environment, you still need a communication protocol for these two components to talk and transfer data. The most common way is using HTTP, which will require you to integrate a HTTP server with your NodeJS app.

In a HTTP model, your client-side AngularJS will make a HTTP request to ther NodeJS app and wait for a HTTP response which in your case, the AngularJS asking for data from the MySQL database.

There are couple of ways to do get a HTTP Server running with your application: [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server) provides really good solutions:

- Using NodeJS built-in http module.
- Using NodeJS Connect module: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#readme .
- Using ExpressJS https://expressjs.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

This is the most clarifing answer that i have found.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699700/3156756

This new app on the client thing changes some development paradigms and it is dificult to understand the big picture.

Basically you will do get/post to push and pull data. 
With this you can create a single api interface for diferent types of clients. browser, iphone, android, windows phone, etc