# Possible to use Nodejs with Angular 4 and MySQL as database?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to get my head into learning SQL and integrating it into my Nodejs/Angular app, but I'm not sure where to start or if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use any database with node.js mysql,postgresql,graphql,redis,mongodb.

Here is link to integration using express which is a node.js framework of various databases https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html.

And angular 4 is a front end framework.It doesn't care what you do in backend.

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible to use nodejs with angular 4 and mysql you can get help from this ans
[see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699700/7808007)