# Cannot GET error using angular js node.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

**this is my index.html**
i'm unable to get output while running npm start in the command prompt
i have tried using localost:8080 and localhost:8080/index.html
but the only output i'm getting is cannot get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

 <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>

 <script src="/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">    
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
      Author:
     <input type="text" ng-model="author">
     <br>
     <br> Title:
     <input type="text" ng-model="title">
     <br>
     <br> Body:
     <input type="author" ng-model="body">
     <br>
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
     </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**this is my app.js file**

i'm unable to get output while running npm start in the command prompt
i have tried using localost:8080 and localhost:8080/index.html
but the only output i'm getting is cannot get

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.submit= function(){

  var data = $.param({

    book: JSON.stringify({

        author: $scope.author,
        title : $scope.title,
        body : $scope.body
    })
  });

  $http.post("/api/book/", data).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log('Data posted successfully');
  })
}
});
```

This is server.js file

i'm unable to get output while running npm start in the command prompt
i have tried using localost:8080 and localhost:8080/index.html
but the only output i'm getting is cannot get

```
var express = require('express'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: 'localhost',
 user: 'root',
 password: '',
 database: 'mydb'
});
connection.connect();

app.post('/api/book', function(req, res, next){
var cope = req.body.params;
var query = connection.query('insert into cope set ?', cope,  function(err,   result) {
 if (err) {
   console.error(err);
   return res.send(err);
 } else {
   return res.send('Ok');
 }
});
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log("listening");
```

Comment: you have to create route for that.

Comment: please explain me in detail @RahulSharma

Comment: Happy to see, you used it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699095/how-to-pass-data-from-angularjs-frontend-to-nodejs-backend/35699700#35699700

Comment: even i have done what u said i'm getting same error

Comment: What is the error. Where do you see the error?

Comment: cannot GET/ is the error while running localhost:8080