# Communicating with DialogFlow from SPA with v2 API

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I am having trouble understanding how to connect a DialogFlow Agent with an Angular SPA using v2 of the DialogFlow API. I want to create a custom component for my chatbot so I don't want to use `iframe`.

With version 1 of the API, one could recreate this architecture with a SPA. There's a good example developed [here](https://github.com/MishUshakov/dialogflow-web).

[image: Architecture 1]

But per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890919/is-it-possible-to-use-dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2-in-front-end-angular), you can't use `dialogflow-nodejs-client` to communicate with your agent from your app. So does that mean we need a server to act as an intermediary like in this 2nd architecture?

[image: Architecture 2]

And then, is there anyway that we can have the Fulfillment functions & the Node server be the same like in this 3rd architecture?

[image]

It would be ideal if anyone could give resources or concrete steps as to how to connect an Angular App with a DF Agent